# /ʊ/, /oʊ/, and /ʌ/ merged before /l/

Tags: american-english, pronunciation, phonology

I merge /ʊ/, /oʊ/, and /ʌ/ before /l/ to form /oʊ/. Soul, bull, and hull all rhyme for me. Is there any record of this merger in US English?

Edit: Dull is in the same class (/ʌl/) as hull. I replaced it with an /oʊl/ word (soul). I say "bull" and "hull" to rhyme with "soul".

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please could you give an example word with /oʊ/ before /l/?

Comment: *Dull, bull, and hull all rhyme for me* I speak British English and they all rhyme... Are you referring to the "dark L"?

Comment: *Dull* and *hull* are supposed to rhyme. They're /dʌl/ and /hʌl/ in the dictionary.

Comment: Bowl also rhymes with those for me.

Comment: @Greybeard In my version of British English 'dull' and 'hull' rhyme, and they also rhyme with 'cull', 'skull' and 'mull', but they don't rhyme with 'bull', 'pull' and  'full'. I have a Derbyshire accent but I can't hear it in RP either to be honest.

Comment: I've never heard of "bull" and "hull" rhyming but it might help to indicate which sound you actually produce.

Comment: It sounds something like [oʟ] to me. /o/ is fronted when not before /l/.

Comment: @BoldBen *"I have a Derbyshire accent"* -- Snap! Me too - Derby itself, and I can hear no difference in any "-ull" sound. To you, is there a "dark L" sound in some of them?

Comment: @Greybeard I grew up in Darley Dale and I know that my accent and dialect sre sightly different from North East Derbyshire but I'm not too sure abou South Derbyshire. I'm also don't know what you mean by a "dark L" sound (unless it's got something to do with the Dark Peak :-}) but I actually produce the 'ull' sound following an explosive consonant from a different part of my mouth and with a different formation of my lips than I do following any other consonant so I don't believe that the two sounds can be the same.

Comment: @BoldBen The American Dark L is explained here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZTgYjGXFAkw. There is also a "Polish L" - Ł,ł  - that is a merged [lw] sound. It is very pronounced (pun!) in Polish, but it also can occur in English to a lesser extent and, as far as I'm aware, not always consistently.

Answer (score 2):

The paper ["North American mergers in progress"](https://www.ling.upenn.edu/phono_atlas/Atlas_chapters/Ch09_2nd.rev.pdf) says the following; I've adjusted the formatting slightly:

> In the course of the study, Telsur found evidence for a number of other mergers of back vowels before /l/ codas. Figure 9.4 shows a merger of /owl/ with /uwl/ and /ul/. Minimal pairs for these contrasts were introduced in the course of the study but not consistently over the whole Telsur sample. In order of frequency of ʻsameʼ responses, these items were:
>
> 1. the merger of /ul/ and /owl/ as in bull and bowl;
> 2. the merger of /ʌl/ and /ohl/ as in hull and hall;
> 3. the merger of /ul/ and /ʌl/ as in the rhyming pair bull and hull;
> 4. the merger of /ʌl/ and /owl/ as in hull and hole.
>
> The ﬁrst three of these at least deserve further study.

You apparently have mergers (1), (3), and (4).

That paper appears to be part of [a project from the early 2000s.](https://www.ling.upenn.edu/phono_atlas/) If there hasn't been more definitive research since then, you may deserve further study.

Comment: That's using /u/ for the vowel of *bull, pull, put, could, hook, cook* where it should be using /ʊ/. That’s really weird! Usually /u/ represents the vowel of *pool, Boole, cool, tool, who’ll*. And what they’ve written /ohl/ is some insane way of writing /ɔl/ as in *all, always, call, tall, Paul, mall, gall, fall*. Gosh dog it!

Comment: @tchrist Yeah, the paper appears to not use proper IPA for some inexplicable reason.